# Mongodb find top 10 largest array items in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection has items like

```
[{
  "username": "xxx",
  "wonTournaments": ['111', '123', '1234']
}, {
  "username": "xxx2",
  "wonTournaments": ['111', '123']
}, {
  "username": "xxx3",
  "wonTournaments": ['111', '123', '1234', '11111']
}, {
  "username": "xxx4",
  "wonTournaments": ['111']
}]
```

I want to retrieve top items of users whose wonTournamnts is more. Can anyone tell me how to do this in MongoDB. I am using cloud MongoDB atlas.

In the above case top users are ['xxx3','xxx','xxx2','xxx4']

Comment: You mean you want to get top 10 users from this collection with most `wonTournamnts`?

Comment: exactly whose wonTournaments array size is bigger he will be the top like that next user wonTournaments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`db.collection.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { username: 1, won: { $size: "$wonTournaments" } } },
  { $sort: { "won": -1 } },
  { $limit : 10 }
])
```

You will need to change `collection` with the name of the actual collection you have in db.

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot It worked.I want to understand what is username: 1

Comment: It simply means what fileds we should include or exclude in `$project`. By using username: 1 we are saying show username also in final output. You can see more details about it in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).